# Insect identification - is it a bed bug?

Tags: species-identification

We were on holiday and got bitten by (most probably) bed bugs. We then carried them home, and I also saw a typical one: 4mm, flat, round, black. I thought it was pretty clear we had bed bugs. I smashed one:

[image]

Currently (2 weeks later) we have a lot of small insects in the house, like shown in the picture. But they don't really seem like bed bugs, do they? The big ones look like bed bugs, but the small ones don't?

What is it? It's around 2mm (others are much smaller, very tiny, less than 1mm). They can jump (or run really fast) 2cm if I try to squash them with a finger.

[image]

Update:

The small one is very similar to a [psocid](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Staublaus_Details.jpg)?!

Update 2:

They have wings.. I think they're psocids.
What I also realized, I probably have two different larves. I take some more probes..

Comment: Top photo looks like a bed bug. Bottom one looks very much like a psocid.